# Injected object with hk2 returns null

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I am trying to use `hk2` dependency injection in `jersey` application. I have a class named `ClassA` implements `IClassA` interface. I want to use dependency injection for `ClassB` object in `ClassA` :

```
package com.example.test

public class ClassA implements IClassA {
    @Inject
    ClassB classB;

    @Override
    public void method() {
        classB.doSomething();
    }
}
```

ClassB :

```
package com.example.test

public class ClassB {

    public void doSomething() {
    }
}
```

I created ResourceConfig class.

```
package com.example.test.di
public class App extends ResourceConfig {

    public App() {
        register(new MyApplicationBinder());
        packages(true, new String[]{"com.example.test"});
    }
}
```

I created AbstractBinder class.

```
package com.example.test.di
public class MyApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ClassB.class).to(ClassB.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

I addded Application to `web.xml`

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.test.di.App</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I created ClassA object like this :

```
IClassA classA = new ClassA();
classA.method(); //--> classB is null
```

My problem is `classB` object is always null in `ClassA`. I cannot find what is wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code where `ClassA` is instantiated.

Comment: Hi @TimMoore, I created ClassA like this on another class : `IClassA classA = new ClassA()`. is this enough for you ?

Comment: That's not how dependency injection works. You needs to let the container create the instance.

Comment: thanks @PaulSamsotha, classB is not null if I use injecton to create classA. But I need multiple instances of ClassA class. I got always same object with injection. so how can I do this ?

Comment: How are you getting the instance? Please show relevant code

Comment: Normally I get different instance of ClassA by using `IClassA classA = new ClassA();`. But I get same object always when I use dependency injection. I want to create different ClassA objects and use dependency injection in ClassA. But I cannot find a way ?

Comment: As other commenters have pointed out @user4757345, `new ClassA()` doesn't invoke the dependency injection mechanism. You'll need to create your instance using the dependency injector. It sounds like your question is really about how to do that and get a new instance each time. Please update your question to show how you've attempted to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have bound ClassB in the Singleton scope (which means hk2 will only create one of them).  Instead, bind ClassB into the PerLookup scope.  Then also inject a javax.inject.Provider.  Every time you call the get method of Provider you should get a new instance of ClassB